How to Backup and Restore a MariaDB database with Master and Slave replication configured?
I have a MariaDB Master and Slave server setup for replication. Both MariaDB servers are in the same datacenter and local network.
I want to do at least a daily full backup and incremental every 15 minutes. Data changes the most between 6am ET and to 1am ET the following day. I use InnoDB storage engine.
From the research I've done so far, mariabackup is what can do full and incremental backups.
Do I perform the full and incremental backup from the master or slave? How can I prevent locking the database from writes so my webapp can still be used during backups?

Yes, mariabackup is probably your best option for this.
You will want to use the slave for creating backups. That way you can still read and write on the master without causing any locking there.
While the backup is running you will want to direct all queries/ statements from the app at the master only.
I'm sure you have found this already, but adding it here for completeness:
Mariabackup documentation
Assuming this is on Linux, then an alternative to mariabackup for full backups could be LVM snapshots combined with the MariaDB BACKUP STAGE commands. All in the same session, do:
BACKUP STAGE START;
BACKUP STAGE BLOCK_COMMIT; 
-- then create the LVM snapshot, then
BACKUP STAGE END;

This kind of backup offers the prospect of a very short backup time - making the snapshot itself is instantaneous but you also need to copy it to somewhere safe (before disposing of the snapshot) and that can take a bit of time, but still significantly less than mariabackup. However, LVM snapshots for MariaDB (or MySQL) backup are poorly documented, and what little documentation that do exist tends to be very old. So, if you just want a decent solution that is well documented and supported, then mariabackup is probably what you want.
Whatever you do, remember to test your backups, i.e. at least restore them, and learn how to do that effectively.

The application doesn't access the slave. I have the slave strictly as a secondary copy to convert to master to get the application back online quickly in case of a master database server issue. The server does not have LVM setup so I cannot take snapshots. I would have to use mariabackup or mysqldump.
